# Spring Boot server error while POST with Retrofit2, only happens when there are relationships in the database

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-boot, retrofit2

I POST some data with Retrofit2 to a Spring Boot REST service and there are a lot of exceptions occurring in the server. This happens when I have relations in my database.

I have a REST service over a Spring Boot application that runs over the Heroku services, I was doing a login and a register tasks with an Android application, I am using Retrofit2 in Android to POST the data to the REST service, everything was working well until for some other reasons I create a relationship between users in my database, this relationship is a "follow", this is, create a relationship in a `follow` table where I have the `ID` of the user that is following and an `ID` of the user that is followed. When I create this relationship into the database and I try to login with the method that I created, I got a bunch of errors into the REST service that I do not know why is this happening.

So in Android I have the call of my Retrofit2 client and a method that creates the service passing as a parameter the `UserService.class` with the HTTP methods. I also pass as a parameter the user of the class `User` where have the information that I want to POST, then I call the enqueue method.

```
RetrofitClient.createService(UserService.class).login(user).enqueue(new CallBack<User>(){
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        //Some logic here
    }
});
```

Into my `UserService.java` I have the method that POST the user object information.

```
public interface UserService {
    @POST("login")
    public Call<User> login(@Body User user);
}
```

Now in the backend side I have a REST controller where I have the login endpoint that will be consumed for Retrofit2.

```
@PostMapping(path = "login", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public Object login(@RequestBody String json) {
    //Some logic here
}
```

As I said this endpoint runs fine when there are no relationships over a user into the DB, but when a user follow another one, this is, when there is a new row into the follow table, lets say:

follow table:

```
id_follow id_user_follower id_user_following
1         1                 2
```

At the example above the user 1 follows the user 2, and when I try to login, this is, use the login method in the `UserService` class it throws me a bunch of errors.

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
```

And this repeat over 300 lines of errors.

The thing here is that between the bunch of error the server return a 200 HTTP response, I managed the exceptions in Spring Boot and I catch that, when I catch I send a code for an error to my Android Retrofit2 client, but the login does not work.

Expected result:

After sending the POST from Retrofit2 to Spring Boot the response have to be a HTTP 200 response but no exceptions have to happen into the server.

Actual result:

There is a 200 HTTP response from the server but there are a lot of exceptions into the server that return an error code to the Android application and the login does not work.

This is the entity that I want to return as JSON from the RestController in Spring Boot.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends AuditModel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1700575815607801150L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "nick_name", unique = true)
    private String nickName;

    private String avatarResource;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String birthDate;

    private String gender;

    private String postalCode;

    private int active;

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public String getAvatarResource() {
        return avatarResource;
    }

    public void setAvatarResource(String avatarResource) {
        this.avatarResource = avatarResource;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(String birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setId(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }


    /* Relations */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Comment> comments;

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserMemory> userMemories;

    public List<UserMemory> getUserMemories() {
        return userMemories;
    }

    public void setUserMemories(List<UserMemory> userMemories) {
        this.userMemories = userMemories;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Vote> votes;

    public List<Vote> getVotes() {
        return votes;
    }

    public void setVotes(List<Vote> votes) {
        this.votes = votes;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userFollower", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Follow> usersFollowers;

    public List<Follow> getUsersFollowers() {
        return usersFollowers;
    }

    public void setUsersFollowers(List<Follow> usersFollowers) {
        this.usersFollowers = usersFollowers;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userFollowing", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Follow> usersFollowing;

    public List<Follow> getUsersFollowing() {
        return usersFollowing;
    }

    public void setUsersFollowing(List<Follow> usersFollowing) {
        this.usersFollowing = usersFollowing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Jackson, so to get out of this problem you most use two annotations in the relations of your entities.

More information, please see the next link: [Here is the answer](https://laptopstouk.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html)

Hope it can help for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

By having `fetchtype.LAZY`, some of the values won't exist during serialization. This will make the `ObjectMapper` to try to fetch these and it all will end up in some kind of infinite loop.

It is never recommended to serialize `@Entity` annotated classes because database tables can change and that in turn will change the API for the calling clients.

Best way is to have specific `ResponseDTO`s that you transfer your data to before serialization so that the API and the database tables can change without breaking anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have a doubt here, lets say that I want to get the information to log in or register a new user, as you can see I am new with this, do I have to create a response/request for every endpoint that I have? I mean, a RegisterRequest with the fields that are going to be send from the client and a RegisterResponse that I am going to send from the the backend to the client? Is this correct?

Comment: usually that is what some people do, or they do some sort of inheritance to reduce the number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that in the backend I was using the `writeValueAsString` of the `ObjectMapper` class like this.

```
public Object register(@RequestBody String json){
    User user = new User();
    user.set...
    ...
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
}
```

For some reason the `writeValueAsString` method gives a StackOverFlowException for a recursive behavior when there is a relationship into the database, this is a problem related with JPA or Hibernate, I am not sure about which one of those.

The solution was to write my own method to build a JSONObject with the information of my POJO:

```
public String buildUserJSON(User user) {
    JSONObject userJson = new JSONObject();
    userJson.put("idUser", user.getIdUser());
    ...
    return userJson.toString();
}
```

And then call this method in my `RestController` to build the JSON that I want to return. As I said I do not know what was the problem but at least this was the solution for me.

Note: I found the solution to this be cause in the past I was with a problem similar like this one but when I was trying to return a `List<T>` as a JSON, so, I though that was related with the same thing.

Regards.

Comment: First of all it is bad practice to create an ObjectiveMapper on each call. It is a big and very expensive object. Second of all spring already has instansiated an object mapper and weill per default serialize and deserialize object for you so you dont have to return Object and build the json yourself. Just return the User and spring will convert it to json for you.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the ObjectMapper, I didn't know that, in the past I was sending the User object as you said but the problem was that the serialization of the object was wrong, the server returned problems of serialization and deserialization so that is why I build the JSON for my own, the deserialization problem only occurs when there is a relationship into the database with the entity returned.

Comment: You havnt posted your User object so i have no idea what you are seeializing and no error msg either.

Comment: I think that the entity, let say in this case, the User object does not have nothing to do here, it could be any object returned in the RestController, the thing here is the deserialization problem in an entity object that have relations over the JPA-Hibernate framework, this gives a recursive behavior and an error is thrown, you can see the error in the question above, is the 5th code part.

Comment: The entity has a lot to do with it. First of all you dont serialize your JPA `@Entity` that is also bad practice. To find out the recursive behaviour i need to see what it is you are trying to serialize. I need to see what annotations you are using and how you have declared your relationship in code. So if you want help you need to post your code in its entirety not just parts of it.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAndolf I just updated my question, please see above.

Comment: you have a `fetchtype.LAZY` in your entity which means that at the time of serialization this object will not exist and the jacksons ObjectMapper will call get on the lazyfields and try to get these from the database. These objects will be fetched from the database and i suspect that this is what is causing your stack overflow.
You should never directly return entities to the calling client. That is bad practice, because you might expose columns and data that you dont want the calling client to see. You should have dedicated responseDTOs that you transfer the data to from the entities instead

Comment: Got it, thank you for your comments and responses. Maybe you can put the last comment as a response, I will mark that as the final and correct response, I already test it and it works, thanks a lot.